# convert PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile to 3 dimension numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, gif

I have a list of different urls. When you click on this url, there could be a picture or a gif on it. My task is to convert gifs and pictures to 3d numpy array. If we talk about gif, the first picture on this gif is enaugh. I wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

my_url = 'https://......'
im = Image.open(requests.get(my_url, stream=True).raw)
np_im = np.asarray(im)
print(np_im.shape)
```

The problem is that when I have a link to picture in my_url, np_im is 3 dimension (3 * size of picture for r g and b). If I do `print(type(im))` I get `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile`
But when I have gif on my link, np_im is only 2 dimensions (only length and width, without r g and b). If I do `print(type(im))` I get `PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile`. How can I get 3 dimension np array for gifs? When I print im to console it staill loks like a picture, so there still should be interpritation of r g and b

Answer (score 1):

I think that I found a long way how to do it. First of all we convert our gif to 4d numpy array

```
frames = np.array([np.array(frame.copy().convert('RGB').getdata(),dtype=np.uint8).reshape(frame.size[1],frame.size[0],3) for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im)])
```

After that we take the first picture of our gif

```
np_im = frames[0]
```

In this case np_im is 3d numpy array, which shape is (length, width, 3)